# php - currency regex not working in php, elsewhere is

Tags: php, regex

I have this pregex `/[A-Z]{3}\s\(.\)/` which is working on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) but when I use it in php with `preg_match()` it returns false with `USD ($)`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
My php version is **5.4.32**

```
if(preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}\s\(.\)/g', $var)){
            return $var;
        }else{
           return 'Money error';
        }
```

This returns "Money error" with $var = 'USD ($)'; for me.

Comment: Please post complete code, with data example and what you expect.

Comment: Works fine for me as is.

Comment: Deleted the g-letter from the end of the regex. Working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **g** attribute after the regex closing from regexr.com that doesn't work with php.

Answer (score 0):

You may not put the `g` at the end of the regex:

```
php > echo preg_match("/[A-Z]{3}\s\(.\)/", 'USD ($)');
1
```

There are [modifiers you can use](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), but `g` is not one of them. To do a global search, use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).